# How to extract CSS color using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a CSS style that I need to extract the color from using a Java regex.

eg

```
color:#000;
```

I need to extract the thing after `:` to `;`. Can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to apply it to Java, but one regex to do this would be:

`^color:\s*(#[0-9a-f]+);?$`

Comment: On a sidenote: This variation will not match the more common version with one or more white spaces after the colon — e.g.: `background-color: #fff;`. Also note that the semi-colon might not be present after the last statement for a selector and should probably be optional.
(There’s more issues like matching colors defined as `rgb[a]` values or named colors but they don’t necessarily fit in scope of this question.)

Comment: @polarblau, I have updated the regex to allow for optional spaces and semi-colon. I agree that your last point is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

To just extract from `:` up to `;` do something like:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^:]*:(.*);");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String value = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println("'" + value+ "'");  // do something with value
    }
```

- `[^:]*` - any number of chars that are not ':'
- `:` - one ':'
- `(...)` - a capturing group

  - `.*`- any number of any character
- `;`- the terminating ';'

use `color:(.*);` for only accepting values for 'color'.

Answer (score -1):

```
/(?<=:).+(?=;)/
```

That will do it for you

Not sure how you implement regex in Java though.

[www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) to help you text out your regex in real time.

Answer (score -1):

The expression

```
":(#.+);"
```

should do it

Comment: I wonder why people vote negative, the expression is correct and it is not missleading

Comment: Yes, but it is greedier than needed; better and safer to just match numbers; the regexp will be faster, and more accurate.

Comment: I agree that it could be better but then that is the purpose of this site, so that he can pick and accept another answer, your argument does not justify negative votes in my opinion, but again, this is just an opinion.